# unable to connect to internet

Tags: networking, dhcp, internet

I am using pi as my main system.

for sometime, i had to start dhclient manully to connect to the internet, to fix this, when i searched on internet, i came to know that i have both dhcpcd and dhclient installed.. so i remove  `dhcpcd5 isc-dhcp-client isc-dhcp-common` packages by seeing the answer,

now i don't have internet

i tried connect internet manually using

```
sudo ip addr add 192.168.1.7/24 dev eth0

sudo ip route add default via 192.168.1.1
```

but it showing error

```
Error:Nexthop has invalid gateway
```

1. is there any way to install dhclient back without internet?
2. any way to connect to the internet without dhcp.

thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you just install a standard OS and don't fiddle with it. Networking works out of the box. If you have some reason to not use the default networking you need to explain.

Comment: i am using default noobs os, without gui, and i installed awesome wm and kde... my problem is, once i installed dhclient to thether phone, since then internet is not starting at boot, but in orderto fix it, i removed some packages ended up breaking the system. yesterday i had cleared apt's cache to save memory, so today i didn't even had a way to install it

Comment:  now i just fixed it by manually downloading those pacakges to phone and trasfered it using mtp to pi, then manully installed using dpkg .. i will give this as answer

Comment: NOOBS isn't an OS it is an installer - which Raspberry Pi Ltd. has finally had the decency to discontinue and has never been default. Do yourself a favour and install Raspberry Pi OS.

Comment: i have been using it for 8 months, i have many importing files in it, and there is no other system with me, except for my compnys one , where i canot install enything else... also  this is really customised  , so until i get a new system, i have no plan to update it, as this works for me ..  and i know noobs is installer, but i meant, i installed the offical one from the installer ...

Comment: okey, sorry i remeber, once i had updated from 32 bit to 64 bit 4oths ago or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i fixed it my self..

i checked

```
\var\log\apt\history.log
```

and find out exact version of pacakges i accidentally uninstalled and
gone to
http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/dists/bullseye/main/binary-arm64/Packages

http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/bullseye/main/binary-arm64/Packages

and find out location of exact package name

then eg:

```
Package: dhcpcd5
Version: 1:8.1.2-1+rpt5
Architecture: arm64
Maintainer: Scott Leggett <scott@sl.id.au>
Installed-Size: 424
Depends: lsb-base (>= 3.0-6), libc6 (>= 2.28), libudev1 (>= 183)....
...
Filename: pool/main/d/dhcpcd5/dhcpcd5_8.1.2-1+rpt5_arm64.deb
```

exits in

http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/pool/main/d/dhcpcd5/dhcpcd5_8.1.2-1+rpt5_arm64.deb

download it in phone.. connect phone to pi using usb cable, transfer it to pi

then install it using

```
sudo dpkg -i <pkgname>.deb
```

start dhcp using

```
sudo dhclient
```

volla! we have internet!  now i can go and study for tomorrow's exam

---

Note :  i recently had removed my apt's cache using

```
sudo apt clean
```

otherwise i would have that deb pacakges in

```
/var/cache/apt/archives/
```